# How to configure monacoeditor custom theme in angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-monaco-editor

Thanks for the support,based on docs provided by monaco-editor, I am able to acheive my 1st milestone  i.e. adding hyperlink to text inside monaco-editor using defineTheme(). Here is the link to what I have till now

[custome theme to show paths as clickable link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAAKeAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMpUO-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWS9TrQEnwCrUIAV5WP_whScBT2qsEf8ZtKWeVt4oDxPhR9ixrAdsAGgjD6XTXJyfF_AN4G9w0CI8xuVVNmj5x0xio_w7p98Cvg25xbQG3Ob85a1LadVKD2IZMZwHw9eQ5ivUQl8gBmMoBzhfrjD4VIEhf2TgZLoV8MpAir3nJ3njcFbQ-eE4GuvueK8qO2PL1_OFe3nkjigt-ixNlXtd79cY27jmSoFfC6nHyJm4jvdONoODjRLUN0iqstvlJcaJ_5gF1emf71DuGv_O9COJQc-5bOf3FC9SBvaFXS3QESJC4kJRJLWk3aTHb9J1-3hZoHg2u70MCdDZVKPdwFsm0kQ2Zi7Gi8H9EmXBP7yVVeod0ScLjkkj8VElu7TH732wvbFFWbIOkwpuQUOekt3Af-mVipELlZhvqfQ7iFQPP6RETBecpKUP1_3XuXMT-0qcJ_Ei38ggFrDAIoEvFO181zNjVdNUCs-KDP9Fgw1aGwbQHp6FyZlGiNV7nI2kAQk4p26XA0rbe-NOOBCOjnf9JdbIgCwLWjtm5d0Z10VAU8PwXV6oiBQxn6Cg-C1VThg1u91AdqyV9L7LaZW1c1wTUqUmupjILJfbL8uUndCMBUhpTsttR0M1Ebg5t3dsNZh_esppB-WbVi9sb8KBxQuie_9El3iA)

However, When I try to use this code in my angular project and I am unable to see the style on link. Can someone please assist to integrate this code in angular?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-monaco-editor-example-t5sbtn?file=app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible but complex.

**First**, for the design, you need to create a custom template. You can be inspired by the example [Token and Colors](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAAJ2BgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMpUO-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWS9TrQEnwCsWy5tSz89-_i43gCCpxv1BSpeuEgdNMIM04PU3A_QpMMxEmMJSKOc5j369orDuoy8V8huycXr_1p34exPZisg9bPqz5ZHmQv3PkbvuqJi59TkZc8yPZAuBzJz2tia_amMQ3rLVsOziT4PyoI4QbCLTErF0jyA637oJBB1x5xM8ULGXrDEdh3Ohw9A2NNmD3yhX9KgItF9URkCjGPhgrBleL8Hw7Avd5W_yGuAspsaahetjiyEiaqrP-Ps9d_veOdTv6jjVh-gSSt_b_J40zVWo8vTQeDM0QPA8e-HrPraSo8Gtrjp4DvLVg4dFMXcNZtN91mwZHf2CkZYZ0m4UNX-r2Ne6Zk_swLgx_Hpq2wN1YRbl-QoAWs2wJwWqMp1479xNEVfxaP7_6DR7CYr9tgVXt65JpKxIUQy_BiQQyzC8oXIuJRHbRTzVesBTu38OiL43Gb-LSzTBZcb5uSlPsiokxqoodxQcGNwHHN5Q3KUiak-y7LFgFSQEscXe7cAPo50_EL4QnCWrqzZfU_IPTEphiCygk_dXZ1BrQWqIo6Byhguz9mHXDVUJhVg9s-75zUSOUAbGyOdIPUDP4xmk0BXW7zonIoL0jGsO2ylJoDUBzrj4L56XjEbB5jbtyAbypFCt4WW_FBX51ceiRPT7y_bwumH-uKK3js0nuV-utX0FB9uh4m2MZ2RIOA5e19PIyXaBbDHhDFi_I7Fv3BW60WxV168Owfdxvq6Eq16TN9LUUN1BzB3wmGFSjeJwZHybnZP9HC-xWRks-VRd4cAcPFdmYmnocIqCp4ttgD3_EniaDha6vvQdz7PcpQZBrng1wqc0hBM90h_okrSKFc94tKxnhdVq4O1P8BhqceGLuTTr5B723YMXXXu5aF2ctibXyJIpcwPDW_3MRGhWoT6tzJBMVnpv1N75FImA3mjn8wgbM0ya5JMxPg0Hi1eyMGclkOWR72VzxLjWqJHbd24mDZqTec54T9dI7piTiSYluifCtpNv_6ieSNQ) from the Monaco editor playground. Keep in mind, that the mouse will not have easily the pointer cursor.

**Then**, you need to listen for the click on your editor

For the `.html`:

```
<ngx-monaco-editor ... (onInit)="onInit($event)"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

and in your `.ts`

```
onInit(editor:any):void {
  editor.onMouseUp((event:any)=>{
      const {endColumn,endLineNumber,startColumn,startLineNumber} = event.target.range;
      const lines = editor.getModel().getLinesContent();

      // Check if the click is on the path (with a regex for example) 
      // and do what you want with that
  })
}
```

Comment: This is helpful! I found this doc for more info but can you tell me how I can use "keyword" to apply the style to my paths in my content. I would like to apply those rules where keyword is 'data/....'             https://help.keyman.com/developer/current-version/reference/editor-themes

Comment: I don't know, sorry.